# Injecting a bean with @Autowired not working

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I am fairly new to spring and I am currently following a tutorial as to how to use services and repositories along with @autowired but after following each step it doesn't seem to be working for me. From reading through the error I am getting I can see that injecting the bean using @Autowired isn't working for a service class I created because it isn't finding a class with the matching criteria.

This is my **service interface.**

```
public interface ArtistService {

void save(Artist artist);

Artist get(int id);

void remove(Artist artist);

List<Artist> findAll();
}
```

This is my **class implementing my service interface**

```
@Service
public class ArtistServiceImpl implements ArtistService {

ArtistRepository artistRepository;

@Autowired
public ArtistServiceImpl(ArtistRepository artistRepository) {
    this.artistRepository = artistRepository;
}
```

(Interface methods are implemented but left out to keep this compact)

And my **boot application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class JdbcTutorialApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

@Autowired
ArtistService artistService;
@Autowired
ArtistRepository artistRepository;

}
```

@Autowired also isn't working for a repository I am trying to add but it's basically the exact same as this, but it's a repository.

The following is the first line of the error I am getting

```
       org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcTutorialApplication': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: ie.cit.oossp.service.ArtistService ie.cit.oossp.JdbcTutorialApplication.artistService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'artistServiceImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Sean\Documents\College\3rd Year\OOSSP\STSWorkspace\JdbcTutorial\target\classes\ie\cit\oossp\service\ArtistServiceImpl.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [ic.cit.oossp.repository.ArtistRepository]: No qualifying bean of type [ic.cit.oossp.repository.ArtistRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [ic.cit.oossp.repository.ArtistRepository] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
```

Comment: create a bean which is a type of ArtistRepository and try again.

Comment: do you have <context:component-scan /> in your application context?

Comment: @JToddler I have a repository class structured basically the same as my service class but with the Repository tag instead

Comment: @Sean, you should have a Spring application context file (XML file) where you define your beans. You must add <context:component-scan /> to it.

Comment: If you don't know that file, please add your XML files to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure your `ArtistRepository` extends `CrudRepository` like below. SpringBoot will find all Repositories automatically and create instances. You do not need to annotate the repository classes.

```
public interface ArtistRepository extends CrudRepository<Artist, Long>
```